# manage.py migrate not being activated in prodcution...column X does not exist...why?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm getting this error;

```
ProgrammingError at /
column main_category.parent_cat_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...n_category"."author_id", "main_category"."image", "main_cate. and I believe this means parent_cat_id isn't in the database.
```

This is what I don't understand, I set it to `null=true` and `blank=true`....and this worked in local development server. The error is occuring only in production.(I'm using elastic beanstalk)

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    parent_cat = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    hotCat = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    sponsored = models.ForeignKey(Sponsored, null=True, blank=True)


    objects = CategoryManager()

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/category/%s/" %self.name

    def get_image_url(self):
        return "%s%s" %(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image)
```

Edit:

This is my python config file, as you can see I have migrate

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python myproject/manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true

  02_uninstall_pil:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && yes | pip uninstall Pillow"

  03_reinstall_pil:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && yes | pip install Pillow --no-cache-dir"

  04_createsu:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python myproject/manage.py createsu"
    leader_only: true

  05_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python myproject/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

  06_checkpermission:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python myproject/manage.py check_permissions"


option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "myproject.settings"
    "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app/myproject:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

My traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/opt/python/current/app/myproject/main/views.py" in index
  64.       request.session['categories'] = [ c.name for c in Category.objects.filter(author=request.user.id)] # add to the session 
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  162.         self._fetch_all()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  965.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  238.         results = compiler.execute_sql()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  97.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
Exception Value: column main_category.parent_cat_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...n_category"."author_id", "main_category"."image", "main_cate...
                                                             ^
```

My migration file

```
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Category',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
            ('name', models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=128)),
            ('description', models.TextField(verbose_name=b'\xec\xbb\xa4\xeb\xae\xa4\xeb\x8b\x88\xed\x8b\xb0 \xec\x84\xa4\xeb\xaa\x85')),
            ('image', models.ImageField(upload_to=b'images/', null=True, verbose_name=b'\xec\xbb\xa4\xeb\xae\xa4\xeb\x8b\x88\xed\x8b\xb0 \xeb\x8c\x80\xed\x91\x9c \xec\x9d\xb4\xeb\xaf\xb8\xec\xa7\x80', blank=True)),
            ('hotCat', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ('active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
            ('author', models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ('parent_cat', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, to='main.Category', null=True)),
        ],
    ),
```

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` with the current state of your models in the production environment? Made sure you commited the migration file to versioning (I sometimes forget that ;) )?

Comment: I believe the error is from somewhere else. Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: You need to make sure your migrations folder includes the lastest migration, also that your settings in the elastic beanstalk include using manage.py migrate your_app in the python.config of the .ebextensions folder

Comment: @schwobaseggl thanks for the comment, I have added it I think....can you please check what I editted? I think what I have is migration file...not 100% sure

Comment: @AbhinavI  thanks for the comment I'm pretty the error means what I'm thinking I posted traceback

Comment: @Aquiles yes I have that in python config in that folder...how do I make sure my latest migration is there? I believe my latest migration is there because it works in local developemnt mode

Comment: check the version you uploaded into EBS and in your app folder there is a folder called migrations there you can see the migrations, check that the one in your production version is the same as in your development version

Comment: Also just to be on the safe side, you might want to check your database and see just how it's set the table in question: to do that, connect to your EC2 instance, and then run mysql -u ebroot -h <rds_instance_url> -P 3306 -p. Once there get to your DB by use ebdb and then check your table by: show create table <your_app>_category

Comment: @Aquiles I have edited with my migrtion file..as you can see parent_cat is there...how do I check the version I have uploaded into elastic beanstlak?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108731/discussion-between-aquiles-and-mike-braa).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because some code that uses this new field is evaluated before the migration script is run, specifically here it is:

```
File "/opt/python/current/app/myproject/main/views.py" in index
  64.       request.session['categories'] = [ c.name for c in Category.objects.filter(author=request.user.id)] # add to the session
```

The solution is to either rewrite that code so it's not evaluated, or temporary comment it out so you can do the migration.

This didn't happen on local because you probably defined a new field in the model, run the migration script, then wrote that view code.